# Mapping a Column from One Dataframe to Another

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to map the values in df2['col2'] to df['col1']:

```
df        col1   col2
0       w      a
1       1      2
2       2      3
```

**I would like to use a column from the dataframe as a dictionary to get:**

```
        col1   col2
0       w      a
1       A      2
2       B      3
```

However the data dictionary is just a column in df2, which looks like

```
df2        col1   col2     
1       1      A
2       2      B
```

I have tried using this:

```
di = {"df2['col1']: df2['col2']}
final = df1.replace({"df2['col2']": di})
```

But get an error: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

I have about a 200,000 rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

The sample dictionary would look like `di = {1: "A", 2: "B"}`, but is in `df2['col1']: df2['col2']`. I have 200k+ rows, can I convert `df2['col1']: df2['col2']` to a tuple, etc?

Comment: A `dict` key has to be a hashable object type, something immutable like a tuple, string, int, etc. You can't  use a df column as a key

Comment: Please add the sample dictionary also.

Comment: Is it possible to convert 2 column pairs into a hashable object type, rather typing it out for 200,000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a lookup dictionary based on the `col1:col2` of df2 and then use that to replace the values in `df1.col1`.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['w',1,2],'col2':['a',2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2],'col2':['A','B']})

print(df1)
#  col1 col2
#0    w    a
#1    1    2
#2    2    3

print(df2)
#   col1 col2
#0     1    A
#1     2    B

dataLookUpDict = {row[1]:row[2] for row in df2[['col1','col2']].itertuples()}
final = df1.replace({'col1': dataLookUpDict})

print(final)
#  col1 col2
#0    w    a
#1    A    2
#2    B    3
```